# Is there a specific range of meditation styles that could help with extreme clumsiness and disconnected mind-body?

Tags: personal-practice, meditation-recommendation, mind-and-matter, meditation-body

I have always been very clumsy, specifically,i am not aware, if that's a correct term,o f where my body is located or how its moving, leading to accidents, over-use of force, hitting things accidentally ,etc.... I have been practicing basic mindfulness meditation,along with zen meditation and it has worked wonders in many aspects of my life. Given that, would there be a specific type of practice which would affect this somewhat disconnected body "syndrome"?, for lack of a better term.

Comment: If you body is clumsy, exercise the body - gym, yoga, martial arts etc. By sitting on the cushion the body won't learn to move gracefully...

Comment: I've also go a real disconnect with my body so I am just taking up Tai Chi at the recommendation of an oestopath and a physiotherapist. Let's see how it goes

Answer (score 1):

Of the four foundations of mindfulness (satipatthana)...
Mindfulness of the body is the main one in western practice already. Transitioning a constant state of awareness of the body into daily life could definately combat clumsiness.
           During meditation just feel all of your entire body at once... be aware of it, the feeling of it sitting there or better yet do walking meditation more... if something comes up, note it how its experienced by the body, then refocus on feeling the body just being a body.

do that regularly and you'll find yourself more aware of it naturally... then its more difficult to be clumsy.